# Maven: Set version before deploy step causes missing artifacts

Tags: java, maven, concourse

I am having an issue with dynamically versioning a very large multi-module Maven build. I have a concourse script that looks like this:

```sh
M2_HOME="${HOME}/.m2"
echo $M2_HOME
M2_CACHE="$(pwd)/maven"
ls $(pwd)/maven/
export VERSION="$(cat version/version)"
ln -s $M2_CACHE $M2_HOME
cp aws-infrastructure/Dockerfile XXXX-target/
cp aws-infrastructure/run.sh XXXX-target/
mvn -s XXXX-code/XXXXAggregateBuild/CI/settings.xml -f XXXX-code/XXXXAggregateBuild/pom.xml -DgroupId=com.XX.* -DartifactId=* -DnewVersion="$VERSION" versions:set versions:commit
mvn -s XXXX-code/XXXXAggregateBuild/CI/settings.xml -f XXXX-code/XXXXAggregateBuild/pom.xml dependency:copy-dependencies -Dversion="$VERSION"
cd XXXX-code/XXXXAggregateBuild/
mvn -e -s CI/settings.xml package deploy:deploy-file -DskipTests -Dversion="$VERSION"
ls -alrt third-party-dependency
ls artifact
ls target
```

When I do not include the set version step the build runs fine and produces all the artifacts in the artifacts folder. When I try to version dynamically using set version the artifacts folder is empty and nothing is pushed to our artifactory repo.

Here is the Maven assembly:

```xml
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>batch-jar-zip</id>
    <baseDirectory></baseDirectory>

    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>artifact</directory>
            <outputDirectory>dist</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>third-party-dependency</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The parent pom is nearly 1,000 sloc long so I cannot upload the whole thing, but I can post pieces of it if it would be helpful. Where could I start to investigate why this issue is occuring?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to publish the error messages from the `mvn` runs.

You definitely have a problem in the `versions:set versions:commit` step. When you commit, the actual file has not been changed yet. I would split both goals into two separate steps.

Comment: There is no error messages when it runs. It builds all the jars (50+ of them) successfully but none of them show up in the assembly.

Comment: Yep, no luck though